# Windows 7 Desktop Eats Files & Folders & Then Burps Them Back Up Again

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-management, file-download

This issue started a month or two ago and it has vexed me ever since. Whenever I download a file from IE or FF, or save an attachment from Outlook 2010 and save to my desktop the file does not show up until I either right-click and choose "Refresh" or hit F5 to refresh the desktop. The same thing happens when I extract a .zip or .rar file to my desktop, doesn't matter the contents of the archive, whether they be files or folders, nor the quantity extracted. It also doesn't matter how many times I download files to the desktop or extract items from an archive, until I refresh my desktop the downloaded files/extracted items remain hidden. This does not happen if I choose any other location as my save to destination - the file shows up immediately upon completion of the download or extraction process. Also this doesn't happen if I copy/paste a file or folder to the desktop. It shows up immediately as normal. Also, if I right-click and create a new folder, or document, etc. it also shows up right away without having to refresh the desktop. If I delete a file or folder it disappears immediately without having to refresh.

I don't use any download managers, this is a ***relatively*** new install of Windows 7 Professional Retail, only about 6 months old, all updates have been installed, and I'm not sure what other information you might find helpful to solve this issue. My user folders (Documents, Downloads, Music, Videos & Pictures) reside on a different HDD other than the OS drive and I have changed the properties to point to their locations on the other drive but that was done immediately after installation of the OS. The Desktop folder and its contents still resides on the OS drive. I'm not sure what other information I may be forgetting to include in this post that you may find useful but please let me know if I can provide you with any other details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:
On the Tool bar, click Organize and choose Folder and Search Options.
Click the View tab, and check to select the Show hidden files and folders option, and click OK.
Then, enter the following directory:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local
```

Find the IconCache.db file, and rename it as IconCache.db.old.

It is possible, that the iconcache.db is corrupted. That results in a non refreshing desktop or incorrect displaying of existant folders and shortcuts.

Comment: Well, so far that has seemed to work. Immediately after renaming the file I downloaded a file from IE and it showed up immediately and then I extracted the file and that folder showed up right away as well. I am going to reboot now and call it a night but so far so good. I'll try again tomorrow and see what happens and update you.  

Thanks So Much. 

Valek

Comment: I also learnde during my apprenticeship: never, never, ever use your desktop as working directory. But I guess thats a matter of taste ;-)

Comment: Hmmm...what reason were you given for that? As you said it is a matter of taste and for me it's just easier to download whatever it is that I'm working on, extract it if need be, install or use or whatever and then move the file to its permanent home on my data drive. Is there a technical reason that you follow that tenet? Maybe I should as well...

By the way, does accepting your answer automatically...close or end this question or is there some other procedure I need to complete? Your solution is still working well thus far but never fear, I have more questions that are stumping me...

Comment: Hmmm, well, it seems as if there may be something else going on with this. As I mentioned earlier your solution worked beautifully - for about 2 or 3 days and then the same thing started happening again. I again renamed the IconCache.db file and the problem cleared up once more - for about 2 or 3 days. So it seems that SOMETHING is continually corrupting my Icon Cache. Any Ideas? Also, should I repost this question as a new one or how does that work? Sorry it took so long for me to get back to this. It has been absolutely CRAZY here for the past month...

Comment: Just update the question with the new status. Oh, and no, I guess there is no technical reason not to download to the desktop. I just learned it that way, that´s why I do it ;-) I´ll keep thinking and looking for another reason why this is happening...